# What lenses can capture pictures of the moon, stars, and landscape best?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, astrophotography, night, landscape

I am wondering what lenses you would recommend that work best in both dark environments and for landscape. I have a Canon EOS Rebel T5, and I'm just looking for something to capture mostly the moon and other landscapes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What focal length lens do I need for photographing the moon?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24651/what-focal-length-lens-do-i-need-for-photographing-the-moon)

Comment: This is not a lens recommendation, but you may find it helpful: [How can I take a picture of the moon as part of a night landscape?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/how-can-i-take-a-picture-of-the-moon-as-part-of-a-night-landscape)

Comment: Are you looking for something that can capture moon as part of the landscape or separate full frame moon pictures and separate landscapes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take the picture in one shoot, I'm sorry to tell you: Forget it. If you can see nice scene does not mean you can shoot same scene too.

If you are willing to "photoshop", you are about to take several shoots in as high cadence as possible to catch nice stars, moon and  landscape. Then merge them in one. Be ready to capture tens of RAW images.

85 % of the work rely on your skill, 10 % on your luck and 5 % on your gear.

I haven't answered the question, have I? I haven't because when you will get skilled to get all from you, you'll know what lenses to use.

**tl;dr**: Look for lenses with lowest f-values and try, try and try with the lens(es) you allready have.

Answer (score -5):

Your best bet will be Tokina 11-16mm f/2.8 for an APS-C sensor
But having said that you need to have a really good tripod

Comment: *Why* is that particular lens the "best bet"?